# R help: consolidate a time vs distance dataset into bins

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with 2 columns (I'm trying this in R). Time and distance. There are 70,000 rows. I want to make a new dataframe where the data is binned by larger time slots. For example, bin the first 20 ms with the sum of the “Distance” values corresponding to rows 1:6.  Return a new dataframe with the binned time value and its corresponding distance value.

```
         Time Distance
1           0    0.000
2           0    0.018
3           5    0.030
4          10    0.037
5          15    0.074
6          20    0.039
7          25    0.063
8          30    0.065
9          35    0.063
10         40    0.088
11         45    0.040
12         50    0.038
13         55    0.062
14         60    0.056
```

...

Comment: This would be easy (perhaps even trivial) if you describe in natural language what the verb "bin" means to you. Is it the last value, the cumulative sum, or the cumulative product? Or something else?

Comment: It would be helpful if OP gives some feedback on the answers.

Answer (score 1):

This way of doing things assumes that the way you collected your data is akin to your example.  That is, that you have Time units going up in 5ms intervals in an even manner.

I was confused by the first two rows as you have Time=0 for both, but different Distances.  I presumed that row 2 of Time=0 and Distance=0.018 was maybe a mistake?   Presuming that you couldn't have traveled anywhere in 0ms.

I therefore worked with this df:

```
   Time Distance
1     0    0.000
2     5    0.030
3    10    0.037
4    15    0.074
5    20    0.039
6    25    0.063
7    30    0.065
8    35    0.063
9    40    0.088
10   45    0.040
11   50    0.038
12   55    0.062
13   60    0.056
```

First, I got rid of the first row.

```
df<-df[-1,]
```

Then I set up the binning info:

```
bin<-20                        # the bin interval in ms
nbins<-max(df$Time) / bin      # the number of bins in the data
repeats<-nrow(df)/nbins        # how many rows are in each bin (assuming Time is incremental in regular nits)
```

And added a variable with the bin information:

```
df$bins<- rep(1:nbins, each=repeats)
```

You can now pick any way you want to sum the data.  I currently like `dplyr` because of the ease with which you can do things to the results"

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
group_by(bins) %>%
summarise (sumdist=sum(Distance)) %>%
mutate(bins=bins*bin)
```

The last row is simply replacing the bin number with the last row's Time of that bin, giving you this output:

```
  bins sumdist
1   20   0.180
2   40   0.279
3   60   0.196
```

Hope this helps or gives you ideas.  Of course, if that 2nd row is not a typo, then I would have to rethink things.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
library(dplyr)
# tbl <- read.table(...) # from above
tbl_df(tbl) %>%
    group_by(bin = Time %/% 20) %>%
    summarise(Distance = sum(Distance)) %>%
    mutate(Time = bin * 20) %>%
    select(Time, Distance)
##  Source: local data frame [4 x 2]
##  
##    Time Distance
##  1    0    0.159
##  2   20    0.230
##  3   40    0.228
##  4   60    0.056
```

There has to be a more elegant way to do this. It can also be done without `dplyr`:

```
ret <- Reduce(rbind.data.frame,
              by(tbl, tbl$Time %/% 20,
                 function(xx) c(xx$Time[1], sum(xx$Distance))))
colnames(ret) <- c('Time', 'Distance')
```

I personally feel that the dplyr solution is easier to read, and it is a little faster than my `by()` implementation:

```
## microbenchmark(dplyr = { ... }, by = { ... })
##  Unit: microseconds
##    expr      min       lq   median       uq      max neval
##   dplyr  971.165 1023.264 1058.486 1108.933 3815.682  1000
##      by 1203.408 1262.111 1300.818 1354.200 7718.682  1000
```

Comment: much more elegant than mine!

Answer (score 1):

Following may be easier to understand since it uses base functions only:

```
ddf = structure(list(no = 1:13, time = c(0L, 5L, 10L, 15L, 20L, 25L, 
30L, 35L, 40L, 45L, 50L, 55L, 60L), distance = c(0, 0.03, 0.037, 
0.074, 0.039, 0.063, 0.065, 0.063, 0.088, 0.04, 0.038, 0.062, 
0.056)), .Names = c("no", "time", "distance"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-13L))

ddf
   no time distance
1   1    0    0.000
2   2    5    0.030
3   3   10    0.037
4   4   15    0.074
5   5   20    0.039
6   6   25    0.063
7   7   30    0.065
8   8   35    0.063
9   9   40    0.088
10 10   45    0.040
11 11   50    0.038
12 12   55    0.062
13 13   60    0.056


ddf2 = data.frame(time2=numeric(), distance2=numeric())
totaldistance =0
for( i in 1:nrow(ddf)){ 
    totaldistance = totaldistance + ddf[i,"distance"]
    if(ddf[i,"time"]%%20==0) {
        ddf2[nrow(ddf2)+1,]=c(ddf[i,"time"], totaldistance)
        totaldistance=0
    }
}

ddf2
time2 distance2
1     0     0.000
2    20     0.180
3    40     0.279
4    60     0.196
```