# How to plot a histogram based on two columns

Tags: r

I have a dataset containing three columns called chr, leftPos and Z Score.
The left pos varies within chr (leftPos is the position of a gene in the chromosome chr- it is specific to the chromosome rather than an absolute numbering system)
I would like to plot the sum of Z Scores based their binned leftPos for each chromosome.

The data looks like this:

```
chr     leftPos   ZScore
chr1    10          5
chr1    10000       4
chr1    17887       4
chr1    19999       4
chr2    24          0
chr2    178        -2
chr2    19000      -2
```

The data prior to plotting should look something like this:

```
chr1
  Bins:    SummedZScore
 1-10000       9
10001-20000    8

chr2

Bins:    SummedZScore
 1-10000       -2
10001-20000    -2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out a [similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25129777/r-help-consolidate-a-time-vs-distance-dataset-into-bins/25131383#25131383) I answered earlier today. For this dataset, try:

```
tbl <- structure(list(chr = c("chr1", "chr1", "chr1", "chr1", "chr2", 
    "chr2", "chr2"), leftPos = c(10L, 10000L, 17887L, 19999L, 24L, 
    178L, 19000L), ZScore = c(5L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 0L, -2L, -2L)), .Names = c("chr", 
    "leftPos", "ZScore"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -7L))

library(dplyr)
tbl_df(tbl) %>%
    group_by(chr, binnum = (leftPos-1) %/% 10000) %>%
    summarise(SummedZScore = sum(ZScore)) %>%
    mutate(binRight = (binnum+1) * 10000) %>%
    select(binRight, SummedZScore)
##  Source: local data frame [4 x 3]
##  Groups: chr
##  
##     chr binRight SummedZScore
##  1 chr1    10000            9
##  2 chr1    20000            8
##  3 chr2    10000           -2
##  4 chr2    20000           -2
```

I've hard-coded `10000` here, but that's easily fixed. The reason I did `(leftPos-1)` was that you wanted 10000 included in the lesser bin, instead of the first of the next bin. The use of `(binnum+1)` is mostly cosmetic, whether you want to know where that bin *starts* or where it *stops*. You could go one step further and add a column so that you could have start and stop numbers for each row/bin.

Comment: That seems to work. I am in R studio and the results I get are Source: local data frame [16,110 x 3]
Groups: chr

    chr binRight SummedZScore
1  chr1  4110000   -0.5970337
2  chr1  4470000    0.5125746
3  chr1  4660000   -0.4909903
4  chr1  4770000   -2.4356511
5  chr1  4910000   -2.9529301
6  chr1  4930000   -0.4881105
7  chr1  5020000   -2.1347880
8  chr1  5700000   -0.8246004
9  chr1  5710000   -3.0196588
10 chr1  5780000  -12.7506332   Is this an oddity of R studio so that it gives me a sample of the results. Can you tell me how I create a dataframe of the results so I can examine

Comment: The result is still usable as a data.frame, but is in a native format of `dplyr`. If you must convert it back to a non-`dplyr`-enhanced data frame, just do `as.data.frame(ret)`. That is assuming you did `ret <- tbl %>% group_by ...`. Oh, by the way, the `tbl_df` is not needed, I could have done `tbl %>% group_by(chr, ...` just as easily.

Comment: OK thats pretty cool- so I get three columns in the resulting dataframe- chr, binRight and SummedZScore. How do I plot the SummedZScore (y-axis) vs the binRight grouped into chromosome (x-axis)?

Comment: Have you tried anything? After loading `library(ggplot2)`, add the following after the `select` portion of the piped command: `%>% qplot(binRight, SummedZScore, data = ., facets = ~ chr)`.